# Angularjs Directive Not Updating from Service

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm new to Angularjs and I'm trying to build a simple location finder widget. I have a service set up to contain the location data in a json block. Then I have a controller for the search form that makes a http call to get the json. Then I update the data in service. The service is also used in the location results controller to set the data for the directives on the front end. I've tried a bunch of different things and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

```
(function() { // start closure wrap

var app = angular.module('store_locator', []);

app.service('$store_location_data', function() {

    var store_location_data = this;

    store_location_data.data = [];

    store_location_data.update_data = function(data) {

        store_location_data.data = data;    

    }
});


app.controller('StoreLocatorFormControllor', [ '$http', '$store_location_data', function($http, $store_location_data) {

    this.search_form = {};

    this.searchLocations = function() {

        $http.get('services/locations/').
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            $store_location_data.update_data(data);

          }).
          error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            alert('fail');

          });

        this.search_form = {};

    } // end form submit

}]);



app.controller('location_results', [ '$store_location_data', function($store_location_data) {

    this.locations = $store_location_data.data;

}]);



})(); // end closure wrap
```

HTML:

```
<form name="storeLocatorForm" ng-controller="StoreLocatorFormControllor as storeLocFormCtrl" ng-submit="storeLocFormCtrl.searchLocations()">
  <p>
    <input ng-model="storeLocFormCtrl.search_form.zip_code" type="text" name="zip_code" value="" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <select ng-model="storeLocFormCtrl.search_form.distance">
      <option value="20">20</option>
      <option value="40">40</option>
      <option value="60">60</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>  
</form>


<div ng-controller="location_results as results" ng-show="results.locations.length">
  <div ng-repeat="location in results.locations">
    <h1>{{ location.name }}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What part is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You are directly assigning service data at the time of loading controller.

You shouldn't do that because when you are assigning data from service the ajax call may just started or might not, but for sure it hasn't completed. So for that reason you service data is empty always.

I'd suggest you to use `$broadcast`, this will be useful in your case.

When you get the locations data inside your controller you will `$broadcast` event inside your controller, and that will listen by the controller whichever listing to that event using `$on`

**StoreLocatorFormControllor**

```
app.controller('StoreLocatorFormControllor', [ '$http', '$rootScope',  '$store_location_data', function($http, $rootScope, $store_location_data) {

    this.search_form = {};

    this.searchLocations = function() {

        $http.get('services/locations/').
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            $store_location_data.update_data(data);
            $rootScope.$broadcast('locationFetched');
          }).
          error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            alert('fail');

          });

        this.search_form = {};

    } // end form submit

}]);
```

**location_results**

```
app.controller('location_results', [ '$store_location_data', function($store_location_data) {
    //will call when locationFetched event gets broadcast
    $rootScope.$on('locationFetched', function(event, data){
        this.locations = $store_location_data.data;
    });
}]);
```

Hope this will be helpful to you. Thanks.

Comment: @dsketch21 does it helpful to you?